# Hoeffding to bound Orlicz norm

Tags: inequalities, orlicz-spaces

I have been reading from Weak Convergence and Empirical Processes, and came across the following: Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be constants and $\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n\sim$Rademacher.  Then

$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\sum_i\epsilon_i a_i\right|>x\right)\leq 2\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2||a||^2_2}\right)$

Consequently, $||\sum_i\epsilon_ia_i||_{\Psi_2}\leq\sqrt{6}||a||_2$.

How does this follow (relation between Orlicz norm of Rademacher average and L2 norm of constants)? Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand these notations, $\Psi_2(x)=\exp(x^2)-1$ and 
$\|Z\|_{\Psi}=\inf \{c>0 : \mathbb{E} (\Psi(|Z| / c)) \leqslant 1\}$. 
So the inequality $\|Z\|_{\Psi}\leqslant c$ means that $\mathbb{E} (\Psi(|Z| / c)) \leqslant 1$. Denote $c=\sqrt{6}\|a\|_2$, $Z=|\sum_i \epsilon_i a_i|$. We have
$$
\mathbb{E} (\Psi_2(Z/c))=\mathbb{E} \exp(Z^2/c^2)-1=-1+\int_0^\infty\mathbb{P}
(\exp(Z^2/c^2)> t)dt=\\
\int_1^\infty\mathbb{P}(
Z> c\sqrt{\log t})dt\leqslant \int_1^\infty \min(1,2\exp(-3\log t))dt<2\int_1^\infty t^{-3}dt=1,
$$
as we need.

Explanations: we estimated the probability $\mathbb{P}(
Z> c\sqrt{\log t})$ from above as $2\exp(-3\log t)$, this is equivalent to $$\mathbb{P}\left(Z>x\right)\leqslant 2\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2||a||^2_2}\right)$$
for $x=c\sqrt{\log t}$. Sometimes this is worse than the trivial upper estimate $\mathbb{P}(
Z> c\sqrt{\log t})\leqslant 1$, that's why the minimum.

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide a little more explanation behind the last two inequalities?

Comment: @pestopasta done. I replaced max to min as it was supposed to be.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you